# Change Google Chrome Homepage - Command Line

Tags: google-chrome, command-line, batch-file, cmd

I need to change the Google Chrome homepage using a .bat file.
The file I want to edit is in the "%LOCALAPPDATA%\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\" folder.

File name: Preferences (it doesn't have extension).

The thing is, I need to change the field related to the homepage, but, if the user has not manually set it up before, this field will not be created in the file.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible to do it on IE and Firefox (with some inline Java manipulation within the batch) but so far I've also not been able to find an answer to this question. There's really nothing to try when the info on how to do it doesn't exist. The closest I've gotten is(run this in the Chrome.exe directory):

```
chrome.exe -homepage "cnn.com"
```

Which spawns chrome and the page cnn.com. But it doesn't actually change the homepage. So the next time you start up Chrome, it's back to whatever your home page was originally set to.

Comment: This just opens `cnn.com`. That is not a valid CLI argument for chrome or chromium. It's also not correctly formed. Traditionally full named arguments are notated with `--` not a single `-`; `--homepage`. https://peter.sh/experiments/chromium-command-line-switches/ for a sizable list of chromium switches.